# Determine Max Threads dynamically in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

is possible to determine the max number of threads per block dynamically? i.e. a function to ask to the GPU the value and store it in a variable. Thanks for your help.

---

Thanks, I determined the max number of threads  with the following code:

```
int dev = 0;
cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, dev);

unsigned int maxThreads = deviceProp.maxThreadsPerBlock;
```

and with this number I calculate blocks and threads for my kernel with this lines:

```
unsigned int blocksNum = 1+((mSize-1)/maxThreads); // mSize is the size of array
unsigned int threadsNum = 1+((mSize-1)/blocksNum);
dim3 dimGrid(blocksNum, 1, 1);
dim3 dimBlock(threadsNum, 1, 1);
...
kernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>();
```

Is this form correct to call the kernel?

Thansk for your help.

---

Ok, I'm using the sum reduction kernel number 6 of Nvidia, and used the sample code, which determine the threads and blocks with the next code:

```
unsigned int threadsNum = (mSize < maxThreads*2) ? nextPow2((mSize + 1)/ 2) : maxThreads;
unsigned int blocksNum = (mSize + (threadsNum * 2 - 1)) / (threadsNum * 2);
```

This code works with my array.

Answer (score 3):

Query the device properties, look at [maxThreadsPerBlock](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#structcudaDeviceProp).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Driver API to acces the properties of a particular kernel (called Function in the Driver API terminology).

Use the API call [cuFuncGetAttribute](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/index.html#group__CUDA__EXEC_1g5e92a1b0d8d1b82cb00dcfb2de15961b)  with the [CUfunction_attribute](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/index.html#group__CUDA__TYPES_1g9d955dde0904a9b43ca4d875ac1551bc) value equal to  CU_FUNC_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_THREADS_PER_BLOCK.

This gives you:

> The maximum number of threads per block, beyond which a launch of the function would fail. This number depends on both the function and the device on which the function is currently loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  the value ([maxThreadsPerBlock](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#structcudaDeviceProp_118f38f08c66c8812b1ddeb16e4bf51a4)) is one of the properties returned by [cudaGetDeviceProperties](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g929dcd9a191e17b7498e7ccaa3d16350).  For a fully worked example take a look at the [deviceQuery sample](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#device-query)

Comment: But there is no guarantee that a given kernel will launch with the result returned in `maxThreadsPerBlock`, which I assume is what the question is implicitly wanting to know.

Comment: True.  I didn't get that out of the question myself.  For example the word "kernel" does not appear anywhere in the question.  And `cudaGetDeviceProperties` *is* "a function to ask to the GPU the value and store it in a variable", precisely.   But of course you are correct, a kernel will launch with exactly the number of threads specified in the launch parameters, assuming these parameters are within the limits defined in `maxThreadsPerBlock` and other relevant parameters, and assuming there are no other extraneous inhibitors to kernel launch.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is cudaFuncGetAttributes if you are using the CUDA runtime API or  cuFuncGetAttribute with CU_FUNC_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_THREADS_PER_BLOCK as RoBiK pointed out in his answer if you are using the CUDA driver API. Both functions are documented in the Execution Control section of the respective API documentation.